# Не добавляется класс в manifests/ Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо указать класс ReceptFrag в intent внутри класса HomeFragment.
HomeFragment видит его. Приложение запускается, но при вызове метода intent вылетает ошибка и говорит о том, что мой класс ReceptFrag не указан в манифесте.

Использую шаблон Navigation Drawer.

Comment: ReceptFrag это фрагмент? С чего бы это фрагмент указывать как активность?

Comment: Как тогда стоит с ними взаимодействовать ?
Есть ли какая-то литература или гайды?

Answer (score 0):

В манифесте нужно перечислять только наследованные от Activity классы. Фрагменты работают совсем по другому. Вы создаете в активити контейнер, обычно это FrameLayout, и внутрь этого лайаута кладете фрагмент. Если сильно примитивно, то выглядит примерно так

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flow);
    Fragment f = new ReceptFrag();
    getSupportLayoutManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameLayout, f).commit();
}
```